# PHP - Set default picture for users

Tags: php, image, upload

I'm creating a profile-system including a profile picture. I want to have a default picture if the user hasn't uploaded a picture. To look what picture fits the user, I use their user_id. But how do I put a default picture?

My current code is;

```
<image src="img/upload/groot/'. $user_id .'.jpg" height="120px" width="120px" /><br/><br />';
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check if the image exists, if it does, show it, if not, show a default image:

```
$userImage = 'img/upload/groot/' . $user_id . '.jpg';
$defaultImage = 'path/to/default/img';

$image = (file_exists($userImage)) ? $userImage : $defaultImage;
```

Then use `$image` as your image `src`:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
```

Comment: Don't forget about `alt` attribute in `img` tag ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check with [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) if file exists. If not, then get path to default img.

```
<?php 
if(file_exists('img/upload/groot/'. $user_id .'.jpg')) {
    $path = 'img/upload/groot/'. $user_id .'.jpg';
} else {
    $path = 'path_to_default_img';
}
?>

<img src="img/upload/groot/<?php echo $path ?>.jpg" alt="" height="120px" width="120px" /><br/><br />
```

Answer (score -2):

You can test for `null` for variable `$picture` and place the default pic name as follows

`<image src="img/upload/groot/'. (is_null($picture)) ? 'default_pic' : $user_id .'.jpg" height="120px" width="120px" /><br/><br />';`

Comment: You're checking if user_id is empty but. The problem will persist, because the user excists but he doesn't have a picture.